# Is there a way to list all resources created by a specific operator and their status?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, kubernetes-operator, gcp-config-connector

I use config connector https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/overview

I create gcp resources with CRDs that config connector provides:

```
kind: IAMServiceAccount
kind: StorageBucket
etc
```

Now what I'd really like is to be able to get a simple list of each resource and its status (if it was created successfully or not). Where each resource is a single line that's something like: `kind, name, status, etc`

Is there a way with kubectl to get a list of all resources that were created by an operator like this? I suppose I could manually label all these resources and try to select with a label but I really don't want to do that

### Edit

Per the comment I could do this, but curious if there is a less unwieldy command

```
kubectl get crds --selector cnrm.cloud.google.com/managed-by-kcc=true \
    -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' | xargs -n 1 \
    kubectl get -Ao jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{" Kind: "}{@.kind}{"Name: "}{@.metadata.name}{" Status: "}{@.status.conditions[].status}{" Reason: "}{@.status.conditions[].reason}{"\n"}{end}' --ignore-not-found
```

Comment: Have you considered a `$ kubectl` command to retrieve this resources like: `$ kubectl get crds --selector cnrm.cloud.google.com/managed-by-kcc=true -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --ignore-not-found`? This command will get all of the resources that are managed by k8sconfigconnector and check with each of them if there any objects created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a bit of research on this topic and I found 2 possible solutions to retrieve all the resources that were created by `config-connector`:

- `$ kubectl api-resources` way
- `$ kubectl get-all`/`ketall` way with `labels` (please see the explanation as it's not installed by default)

The discussion that is referencing similar issue can be found here:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: kubectl: Issue 151](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151)*

---

#### `$ kubectl api-resources`

As pointed in the comment I made you can use the following expression:

```sh
kubectl get crds --selector cnrm.cloud.google.com/managed-by-kcc=true -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --ignore-not-found
```

Dissecting this solution:

- `kubectl get crds --selector cnrm.cloud.google.com/managed-by-kcc=true`

  - retrieve the `Customer Resource Definitions` that have a matching selector
- `-o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'`

  - use the `jsonpath` to retrieve only the value stored in `.metadata.name` key (get the name of the crd)
- `| xargs -n 1 kubectl get`

  - pipe the output  to the [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) and use each `CRD` retrieved from previous command to run `$ kubectl get <RESOURCE>`
- `--ignore-not-found`

  - do not display a message about missing resource

This command could also be altered to suit the specific needs as it's shown in the question.

> **A side note!**
>
> Similar command is referenced in the github link I pasted above:
>
> - *[Github.com: Kubernetes: kubectl: Issues 151: Comment 402003022](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151#issuecomment-402003022)*

---

#### `$ kubectl get-all`/`ketall`

Above commands can be used to retrieve all of the resources in the cluster. **They are not available in default `kubectl` and they need additional configuration.**

More reference about the installation can be found in this github page:

- *[Github.com: Corneliusweig: Ketall](https://github.com/corneliusweig/ketall)*

Using the approach described in the official Kubernetes documentation:

> Labels are intended to be used to specify identifying attributes of objects
>
> *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Overview: Working with objects: Labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)*

You can label those resources created by config connector (I know that you would like to avoid it) and look for this resources like:

- `$ kubectl get-all -l look=here`

```sh
NAME                                                                      NAMESPACE         AGE
storagebucket.storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/config-connector-bucket       config-connector  135m
storagebucket.storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/config-connector-bucket-test  config-connector  13s
```

> This resources have the `.metadata.labels.look=here` added to it's definitions.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Config Connector: Docs: How to: Getting Started](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/getting-started)*
- *[Thenewstack.io: Tutorial use google config connector to manage a gcp cloud sql database](https://thenewstack.io/tutorial-use-google-config-connector-to-manage-a-gcp-cloud-sql-database/)*

Comment: This feels like a feature that should be ootb with kubectl. I hope they had something like this. I also dont like having to do that parsing to get a nice table with the additional fields I want (status, etc). Does ketall make that part easier?

Comment: Having limited experience with `ketall` all I can say is that I used it in the same way like the first option `-o jsonpath.....` . As for the ootb feature, it's more described in the github issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way suggested in GCP config-connector docs:

```
kubectl get gcp
```

from https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/monitoring-your-resources#listing_all_resources